# Ubuntu 20.04: Wi-Fi very slow (RTL8723AE)

Tags: wireless, 20.04

*Hello, and I'm very new to Ubuntu, and linux in general. I installed Ubuntu with Windows 10 Pro for dual boot.*

Now, I'm only a laptop user, and I am dependent on Wi-Fi. In Windows 10, my download and upload speed is usually 2mbps, but sometimes I get upwards of 20mbps (good times when Philippine Internet was still good). I never saw Windows report anything lower than an excellent signal.

In Ubuntu 20.04, speeds are usually 60kbps, and never goes above ~150 kbps. The Wi-Fi icon always shows half bars.

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but here's my Wi-Fi Adapter (Realtek RTL8723AE).

I'm sure others have already asked this question, and I have tried some solutions, but none worked. And I tried too much to remember ._.

Comment: Have you already check additional drivers?

Comment: Yes, I installed additional drivers with instructions from

https://seyferseed.ru/en/life-en/ubuntu-realtek-rtl8723ae-driver-fix-slow-wifi-speed-fix.html

Comment: Correction: No, I did not install drivers. lwfinger/rtlwifi_new apparently no longer exists. I only did the other things in the website.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing non-free drivers from https://packages.debian.org/en/sid/all/firmware-realtek/download. just download the package, then run

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite firmware-realtek_20210208-4_all.deb
```